# Why is there weight paint on no deform?

Tags: armature, bones, weight-painting

I turned off deform by checking the button for my bicep bone so the three little bones inside would have more control. But when I went into wight paint mode there was still some wight on it which is odd because the bone on the left of the image facing vertically next to it has no wight when I checked it off. Is this a glitch or did I do something wrong? [image]

Comment: Turning off deform doesn't get rid of the vertex group, if one already existed.  It remains, with the same values, even if those values are no longer being used by the armature.  Vertex groups are used for much more than just weights, and it would be inappropriate if Blender deleted them just because a bone with that name had deform disabled.  TLDR: it's fine, you did nothing wrong, it's not a glitch, and that bone won't affect your armature deformation.